# Why does this call not wait for the response before continuing?

Tags: javascript, promise

When I run this code, this is the result in Chrome Debugging Tools:

need to load metadata 
after Init 
finished z

I was expecting the "after init" to appear only once the "finished z" code had fired, however it seems to be returning before. why is this? (I am new to promises and async programming in JS)

Class1.js:

```
 function activate()
    {
        dataServiceHelper.initBreezeMetaData().then(console.log('after Init'));
    }
```

dataServiceHelper.js:

```
function initBreezeMetaData()
{
    if (manager.metadataStore.isEmpty())
    {
        console.log('need to load metadata');
        return manager.fetchMetadata().then(function ()
        {
            console.log('loaded metadata for ' + config.serviceUrl);
        }).fin(function ()
        {
            console.log('finished z');
        });
    } else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> .then(console.log('after Init'));
> ```

Here you're *calling* `console.log` and passing the result (`undefined`) to `then`. You need to pass a callback function, just as you did in `initBreezeMetaData`:

```
dataServiceHelper.initBreezeMetaData().then(function() {
    console.log('after Init');
});
```

---

> ```
> return true;
> ```

If the `initBreezeMetaData` function returns a promise, it should *always* return a promise. Returning a boolean would cause an exception when the caller wants to invoke a `.then` method on the result…

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. So with your comments on always returning a Promise - how would I do this in my initBreezeMetaData method if I don't always need to call manager.fetchMetadata()?

Comment: I'm not sure what that manager and its metadatastore already do, but theoretically you just should memoize the result of the function. When `initMetaData` is called first time, it will call the manager to fetch metadata, and store that promise. During the fetching further calls will be answered with the stored, pending promise; and after that calls can just return the fulfilled promise.